# Load images from NSURL async with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, asynchronous, uiimageview, restkit

Is there a wrapper or some sort of built-in functionality available in `RestKit` to load a `UIImage` from an `NSURL` asynchronously using callbacks or blocks? I could not find such a method in the `RestKit` docs. If there is not, what is a good strategy for implementing lazy loaded async images from `NSURL` *using* `RestKit` as much as possible?

Comment: I use restkik to load images, for this i use base64 ... only way that i found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using RestKit you can use `RKRequest` to load the data for the image in a manner such as:

```
RKRequest* request = [RKRequest requestWithURL: url];

request.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse* response) {
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: response.body];
    // do something interesting with the image
};

request.onDidFailLoadWithError = ^(NSError* error) {
    // handle failure to load image
}

[imageLoadingQueue addRequest: request];
```

Note that even in the `onDidLoadResponse` case you may want to check `response` to make sure the type of data is what you expected. The image loading queue used above can be created like so:

```
imageLoadingQueue = [RKRequestQueue requestQueueWithName: @"imageLoadingQueue"];
[imageLoadingQueue start];
```

Comment: The compiler cannot find a definition of RKRequest when I use #import <RestKit/RestKit.h>, does RKRequest still available in RestKit ?

Answer (score 19):

Not sure about a RestKit solution, but [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)  is a library that will let you easily load images asynchronously by adding a category to UIImageView, so all you have to write is this (for example):

```
[myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: Well, that's pretty awesome... I got it up and running in < 5 mins with no thought. I'll hold out on accepting until I see if there are any RestKit based solutions.

Comment: SDWebImage also does image caching. AFAIK, RestKit does not.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the right answer, didn't see any RK implementation that comes close to SDWebImage features.

Comment: great one! It's also available as Cocopod which makes life even easier