# RestKit: How to download an image from a server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, restkit

I need download an image from a server but want to add a few parameters to my request

for example

```
"size" : {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
    }
```

(this parameter is used to crop the image)
so,

How can I download an image with parameters using RestKit?

Comment: Don't use RestKit for this, use AFNetworking...

Answer (score 0):

How will it be cropped?  The parameters you have indicted only dictate size.  Also, my suggestion is to store the images (assuming you have control) in a size more usable by your application or write your own web-service to resize the image on the server and pass back the data for a properly sized image.

I have an app that gets phonebook data and we store a separate set of images just for the app that are resized for the small display of an iPhone.  I use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and take advantage of image caching though.  Bottom line is that you ought to store assets in the most efficient form possible for your use.

If you have no control and cannot write your own web-service to resize the image before sending to the app, then you will need to resize the image once the app has retrieved it.  Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12031466/585320) for dealing with web images using `RestKit`.  This is resource intensive on the iDevice and should be avoided if possible (by using one of the two methods I mentioned).

Comment: FYI: The answer you link to uses an old version of RestKit and may not be a viable option for the OP